# Runaway mongodb connections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have set my mongodb `"poolSize": 100` but I'm still seeing my connections count in the metrics skyrocket up to 1,500 before the server forces it them to reset. Every single API call to my node.js application is adding a new connection. Here is my server.js function for setting up my db connection:

```
const db = mongoose.connect(config.db, {
    'useNewUrlParser': true,
    'useUnifiedTopology': true,
    'useFindAndModify': false,
    'useCreateIndex': true,
    'poolSize': 100
}).then((db) => {
    const app = require('./config/express')(db);
    
    require('./config/passport')();
    
    app.listen(config.port);
    
    exports = module.exports = app;
    
    console.log('App started on port ' + config.port + ',  node_env: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
}).catch(error => { throw error});
```

Is there something more to setting up pool size that I need to do in addition to my `"poolSize": 100` setting above?

Comment: The poolsize is set for each connection. How many nodejs processes do you have? Does express server restart?  Are there any other places where you use `config.db` or clone connection from `db` . If you confirm new connections on each API call, it spells you  connect to mongodb on each request. There is not enough information in the question to suggest where exactly it happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration option named `poolSize` supported by `mongoose` or `MongoDB NodeJS Driver`. The two supported options are `maxPoolSize` and `minPoolSize`. You need to use `maxPoolSize` to limit the maximum number of connections. Check the list of supported options here:

[Mongoose Config Options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)